# How to verify that i get only one key from JSON response?

Tags: json, ruby, rspec

I get a response in JSON and need to make sure that i get only one 'signal' in signal_events. I'm using Ruby with rspec.

```
"signal_events": [
{
  "id": "587e9ae969702d10bd5a0000",
  "created_at": 1484692201,
  "geo": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -153.45703125,
      59.67773438
    ]
  },
  "expires_at": 1484778601,
  "geohashes": [
    "bddg",
    "bdeh"
  ],
  "signal": {
    "id": "587e9ae969702d0911060000",
    "created_at": 1484692201.24,
    "expires_at": 1484778601.24,
    "signal_at": 1484691607,
    "source": "usgs",
    "updated_at": 1484692144,
    "magnitude": 2,
    "radius": 6.36107901750268,
    "event_name": "earthquake",
    "tsunami": "no"
  },
  "signal_type": "earthquake",
  "centroid": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -153.45703125,
      59.67773438
    ]
  },
  "location": {
    "country": "United States",
    "country_code": "US",
    "city": "Kenai Peninsula Borough",
    "region": "Kenai Peninsula Borough",
    "region_code": "AK"
  }
},
```

Comment: I noticed you never accept the answers given to your questions. Make sure to go over your questions some time and accept the best answers given they solve your question. This way you let the community know, that the problem is solved and at the same time you reward the effort of the one, who has provided the solution

Comment: I'm pretty new to stackoverflow and will follow your advice in future, Andrey

Comment: In terms of accepting the answers you should be looking for a checkmark under the answer score.

Comment: I wonder how this question could get ever upvoted. Neither any effort is shown, nor the question itself is clear by any means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hash ***can not*** contain duplicated keys, so you will always have one value for any given key.

Comment: That's a good point, Andrey!!!Thank you! Looks like there is no need to double check keys in the response

Comment: I do not follow; `signal_events` is an array, not a hash. The question is unclear, though.

Comment: @mudasobwa I think OP meant the `"signal"` key inside the hash, which is an element of the `signal_events` array.